# How to Write logs into new file from Code Repository in foundry Platform

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

In code Repository when I am previewing or testing *.py file I need to put all logs into a file if already file exists logs should be appended to that file with time. Can anyone please suggest a way for this?

Explanation:
I was doing pytest to test my code functionality so I want to keep test results into file that can be of .txt as I will specify the path of the file the file need to be created in the path specified with test results in it, if again tests are runned then that test results should be appended to the same file with timestamp.

Comment: @Monica-Gaddipatti someone is voting your answer to be closed due to lack of clarity. I would encourage you to provide more detail in the future to avoid it. Things that can help making it more specific: Are you trying to log the test results of a unit test? Or from running a build preview?  What does a file mean, are you trying to create a new file in your repo via a transform (not trivial and/or not doable depending on your security settings), or a dataset? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was doing pytest to test my code functionality so I want to keep test results into file that can be of .txt as I will specify the path of the file the file need to be created in the path specified with test results in it, if again tests are runned then that test results should be appended to the same file with timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

The CI shouldn't push things to git. To be honest I don't even know if it has write permissions. This means that you can't write your test results to a file within a foundry CI run. The test results are always available in the CI runs though, you just need to open the checks to see them.